# How to make whitespace, newlines and tabs visible in jedit

Tags: jedit

I am working with jedit, and I want to know that how can I make whitespace, tabs and newlines visible in jedit. So far I have created the toggle button for the same. But not getting any clue which file should I modify.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what you mean by "you created a toggle button and searching what for to edit." Do you mean in the source code? Just install the Whitespace plugin, it does exactly what you are after. Most functionally in jEdit is added by plugins.

Comment: Let me explain you, so first I imported the source code to eclipse and located files to add the button in the toolbar under "View" dropdown menu For e.g. I created "Show-Hide-Whitespace"button by adding few lines to the file Jedit_gui.props, this file is already there in the source code, and got the checkbox in front of it by adding few lines to the file actions.xml. But I want to make button to be workable. For e.g. If I check the checkbox, it should display all the characters for whitespace,tabs and newlines. For eg. if jedit is using '$' symbol it should display '$' instead of whitespace.

Comment: But I don't understand why you want to change the sourcecode of jEdit. All that you want is already possible out-of-the-box. Just install the Whitespace plugin and then add a toolbar button or context menu entry via the settings dialog that executes the action the Whitespace plugin adds to jEdit. Additionally it will already add an entry in the Plugins menu.

Comment: I don't want to use plugin, want to make it on my own way, so I want to add method to the already existing code. But I am not able to locating particular file, where should I make changes. Can you kindly tell me in which particular file or files, should I add?

Comment: I don't know, i don't think about reinventing the wheel usually. Maybe TextAreaPainter is the right class to start.